# How should I show that $S[y]$ is invariant under the scale transformation?

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

Let $0<a<b$. Consider the functional $S[y]=\int_{a}^{b}x^5(y'^2-\frac{2}{3}y^3)dx$. Show that $S[y]$ is invariant under the scale transformation $\bar{x}=\alpha x, \bar{y}=\beta y$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants satisfying $\alpha^2\beta=1$.

Here's my work:

Consider the functional $S[y]=\int_{a}^{b}x^5(y'^2-\frac{2}{3}y^3)dx$ with $0<a<b$.

By substituting the scale transformation $\bar{x}=\alpha x$ and $\bar{y}=\beta y$, we obtain:

$\bar{S}[\bar{y}]=\int \bar{x}^5(\bar{y}^2(\frac{d\bar{y}}{d\bar{x}})^2-\frac{2}{3}\bar{y}^3)d\bar{x}$.

Note that $\bar{x}^5=\alpha^5 x^5, \bar{y}^2=\beta^2 y^2, \bar{y}^3=\beta^3 y^3$.

From here I'm stuck. How should I find $(\frac{d\bar{y}}{d\bar{x}})^2$? I know I should first find $\frac{d\bar{y}}{d\bar{x}}$ but how should I do so? How about $d\bar{x}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with a simple chain rule.  First, notice that

$$ d\bar{y} = \frac{d\bar{y}}{d\bar{x}}d\bar{x},$$ but also $d\bar{x} = \alpha\, dx$ and $d\bar{y} = \beta\,dy$.  So, it follows that

$$ dy = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}\frac{d\bar{y}}{d\bar{x}}dx = \frac{dy}{dx}dx, $$ and therefore $d\bar{y}/d\bar{x} = (\beta/\alpha)dy/dx$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I already took it from where you left off and learned how to solve this problem. I also spot a mistake above in my work. Thank you so much!